# How reload div every 3 minutes

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div with id "myDiv" and i would like to update it every three minutes with content from a php file. 
Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#myDiv').load('/path/to/script.php');
}, 180000);
```

Note: the last argument is the number of **milliseconds**, that is why it is `3 minutes * 60 * 1000`

Comment: @cbrandolino: assuming he tagged question with `jquery` tag not accidentally ;-)

Comment: how silly am i? btw, it was anyway a reasonable assumption - one of the +1 is mine ^^

Comment: @cbrandolino: did not want to hurt you ;-) Anyway, most of people who ask such trivia question do use jquery ;-)

Comment: jquery is a part of javascript =P i also plus one on it

Answer (score 0):

you can use the setTimeOut() to communicate w/ php VIA AJAX and update the content of div id='myDiv' with the callback.
[setTimeOut method](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)